# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred in mscorlib.dll C#

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which I am populating from a list of objects. However my the 2nd loop through my `foreach` results in an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (Abonat abonat in list.getAbonati())
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = abonat.id; //exception occurs here on second loop
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = abonat.prenume;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = abonat.nume;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = abonat.adresa;
    i++;
}
```

The first time the `foreach` runs, everything is fine, it even shows up in the DataGridView, but the 2nd time, I get the exception (actually it says **A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**) and my form is shown, without running the rest of the foreach.

Any help on this? I've tried instancing the `dataGridView1.Rows[i] = new DataGridViewRow();` but it's read-only.

Comment: There should be a message in the exception - it's not terribly helpful without that. What's the value of `i`?

Comment: You haven't showed us where you define/increment i.

Comment: `i` is 0 at the beginning and 1 when the "possible" exception occurs.

Comment: What is the value of `Rows` when this code runs?  Maybe it doesn't have as many rows as you think it has?  I don't know when this code runs, so I can only speculate.  Maybe the grid has rendered and is empty or contains only a single row?  Why, specifically, are you looping like this instead of binding data to the control?

Comment: You probably forgot to add the row first,  dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

Comment: @David shouldn't it have as many rows as I want? I mean I'm not setting the number of rows anywhere, so maybe it only has 1. In this case, how can I add another row? I am looping like this, because it's the only quick way I know how to do it.

Comment: Use `dataGridView1.Rows.Add()`. You can see that in action here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Comment: That was it. Thanks @HansPassant and rsbarro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create rows before trying to access them;

```
int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = title;
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dateTimeNow;
```

Then you'll be able to access them via dataGridView1.Rows[**n**].Cells[0].Value = x;

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Add the following above your code

dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;

Answer (score 0):

You can not add it this way. For starters it is not know or defined but then you increment it. You can add as many rows you want but you are adding them incorrectly is what we are trying to tell you.

incorrect usage here: dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = abonat.id;